# Fetch only some fields on find in CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

My problem is when I fetch data of user  from users table , all the fields of user table fetched from users table..but i don't want to include password and email address into that so is there any way to only fetch fields other  than password and email address?

regards.

Comment: You have tags for three different CakePHP versions. Which is it?

Comment: Anyway, why do you care if the password and email are included in the query? You don't have to actually *show* them to the user even if they're in the result.

Comment: ya we will not show that to user but if there are more users than it will take less time if we are fetching all fields than some fields...

Comment: You're micro-optimizing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by [juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229470/fetch-only-some-fields-on-find-in-cakephp#comment19741060_14229470) you don't need to use all fields that are returned by your find call. It's not clear what actual problem you're trying to solve and it would be in your interest to clarify such details in future questions.

### For direct queries

For queries directly on your user model you can use some logic like this:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    if (empty($queryData['fields'])) {
        $schema = $this->schema();
        unset($schema['password']);
        unset($schema['email']);

        foreach (array_keys($schema) as $field) {
            $queryData['fields'][] = $this->alias . '.' . $field;
        }
        return $queryData;
    }

    return parent::beforeFind($queryData);

}
```

### However

This won't do anything for queries where you query another model e.g.

```
$results = $PostModel->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('User')
));
```

In the above case, all user fields will be returned. For uses like this it's probably best to define your field list explicitly rather than rely on any automatic magic:

```
$results = $PostModel->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('User')
    'fields' => array('Post.*', 'User.name')
));
```

Comment: ya we will not show that to user but if there are more users than it will take less time if we are fetching all fields than some fields... thanx

Comment: It's a better idea if you _request only the fields you want to use_ - what you've asked for is not that. However if performance is the reason - you aren't going to notice any difference.

Answer (score 2):

you have to do something like this

```
$this->Model->find('all',array('fields'=>array('id','name')));
```

Just mention your require fields on fields array.

if you want to fetch from model then try this

```
$this->find('all',array('fields'=>array('id','name')));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanx for reply...but i want to do this in my model so that by default model will fetch only some fields from database.

Comment: i did exactly same...

return $this->find('all',array('fields'=>array('id','username')));

now i want to add condition in this like 
array('condition'=>array('User.id'=>CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id')

how can i do this in my model?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->User->find('all',array('fields'=>array('User.id','User.name','User.created', etc etc)));
```

You may notice I use Model.field in my field declarations, this is just in case you have any conflicting field names in any related models.

Taken from the [CakePHP manual found here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), all of these below options are available to you when using the Find method on Models....

```
array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'), //array of field names
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'), //string or array defining order
    'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset' => n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
)
```

Comment: thanx for reply but i want to do this in my model so i don't have to write this every time in controller...What i know is we can make over custom method for it....is there any way other than custom method in model then please tell me,,,,regards...

Comment: CakePHP does not really think like that, there is no way to specify which fields are returned by default from a Model.php without alot of code, which is probably counterproductive. Sounds like you need to create two Models...User and UserDetails.. store any fields you do not want returned by User finds in UserDetails and link the two.. when you then do calls on UserDetails you would have to make recurive=1

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `User` model:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    if (isset($this->includeAllFields)) {
        return $queryData;
    }

    if (empty($queryData['fields'])) {
        $queryData['fields'] = array(
            // Specify all fields EXCEPT for "password" and "email".

            'User.field1',
            'User.field2',
            'User.field3'
        );
    }

    return $queryData;
}
```

`$this->includeAllFields` is not part of CakePHP; it's a custom property that I made up. If, for whatever reason, you need to include the password and e-mail address, just add `$this->User->includeAllFields = true;` before the find.

The only downside to this approach that I can think of is that if a field is ever added to or removed from the database, the array of fields in the above code will need to be updated.